# How to Filter between date in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a filter between Dates in ASP MVC but I get always this error :

> Cannot convert null to 'System.DateTime' because it is a non-nullable
>   value type

This is what I wrote my View (~/Home/Index.cshtml) :

```
@{
    var fromDate = (DateTime)ViewBag.fromDate;
    var toDate = (DateTime)ViewBag.toDate;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ProjectReport", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div>From Date: @Html.TextBox("fromDate", string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyy}", fromDate), new { @class = "DatePicker" })</div>
    <div>To Date: @Html.TextBox("toDate", string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyy}", fromDate), new { @class = "DatePicker" })</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".DatePicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
     });
  });
</script>
```

and Controller :

```
public ActionResult ProjectReport(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate)             
{
    if (!fromDate.HasValue) 
        fromDate = DateTime.Now.Date;            
    if (!toDate.HasValue) 
        toDate = fromDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now.Date).Date.AddDays(1);               
    if (toDate < fromDate) 
        toDate = fromDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now.Date).Date.AddDays(1);            

    ViewBag.fromDate = fromDate;            
    ViewBag.toDate = toDate;            

    var voitures = db.Voitures
              .Where(c => c.ConstructionDate >= fromDate && c.ConstructionDate < toDate)
              .ToList();
    return View(voitures);        
}
```

I have a warning in the console :

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Warning CS0472
>   The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of
>   type 'decimal' is never equal to 'null' of type 'decimal?'
>   CarManagement
>   C:\Users...\CarManagement\CarManagement\Controllers\HomeCo‌​ntroller.cs  73  Activ‌​e

The controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{ 
    private CarManagementContext db = new CarManagementContext(); 
    public ActionResult Index(string SortOrder, string SelectedMarque, string SelectedModele, string SelectedDate, string SelectedPrice) 
    { 
        { 
            ViewBag.Marque = String.IsNullOrEmpty(SortOrder) ? "Marque_desc" : ""; 
    .../...
```

Comment: @YvetteColomb I have a warning in the console :
 Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning CS0472 The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'decimal' is never equal to 'null' of type 'decimal?' CarManagement C:\Users\aganfoud\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\CarManagement\CarManagement\Controllers\HomeController.cs 73 Active

Comment: @Anouar No where in the `Index` action are you setting those properties on the `VIewBag`. So they will obviously be null in the View. I suggest you create a view model for the view that encapsulates the data you want to utilize in the view.

Comment: @Anouar all of those values that you are assigning to the ViewBag should be in a ViewModel and passed to the VIew. That is what they are for.

Comment: @Nkosi but can I redirect the data from this controller to another new view ?

Comment: @Anouar Why are you trying to do that in the first place?

Comment: @Anouar That error is **nothing** to do with your original post (i.e. the dates). My suggested change will fix the date error. As @Nkosi states, you need to populate your ViewBag in your `Index` function. Every mention of `ViewBag.Something` in your view means you should populate `ViewBag.Something` in your `Index` function. Also, some of your `ViewBag` references (e.g. `"ViewBag.SelectedModele"`) should likely have the `"` removed from around them.

Comment: Folks, code ***never*** belongs in comments or on PasteBin. If you need to add code to support your question, you should [edit] it directly into the question. If it's too long to add, then you are adding too much code and should create a [mcve] instead. Comments are also not for extended discussion or debugging sessions.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your controller you add optional `DateTime?` objects to your `ViewBag`. Instead try to hand over the value and not the optional like so:

```
ViewBag.fromDate = fromDate.Value;
```

If there is still an exception it should be thrown inside the controller telling you that you have to set the date variables correctly.

Comment: No it is not solution. How do you know that error occurred in this line?

Comment: read his comment. the error is happening is the view and not in the controller

Comment: Are you saying that you still get the error from inside the view?

Comment: From the error message I implied that this error is not thrown in the browser but inside the view code (when rendering the view).

Comment: It doesn't need to be from JS,. In the View you have also server side code snippets - var fromDate = (DateTime)ViewBag.fromDate; - and there also would an exception occur

Comment: But then this statement contradicts the code the OP gave us and he should clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

The ViewBag data is null, as you are not creating it, in the controller.

You need to create these values in your controller that is rendering the view.

```
public ActionResult Index(.../...

    ViewBag.fromDate = somedate;
    ViewBag.toDate = somedate;
```

You are getting values for fromDate and toDate to use for your dates and you are initialising them against null - these ViewBag variables do not exist.

```
@{
    var fromDate = (DateTime)ViewBag.fromDate;
    var toDate = (DateTime)ViewBag.toDate;
}
```

You are also  passing the DateTimes as optional parameters - so you need to check them as being null:

```
public ActionResult ProjectReport(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate)
{
    if(fromDate == null)
        var fromDate = new DateTime();
    if (!fromDate.HasValue) fromDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    if(fromDate == null)
        var fromDate = new DateTime();
    if (!toDate.HasValue) toDate = .../...
```

Make sure you've initialised your DateTime values in the code behind, before trying to access them in the view.

Comment: The `var fromDate` - will that compile given there is a parameter with the same name?

Comment: there is formDate und toDate

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is happening because you are trying to cast a null to datetime in your view. You can do this is the view to check for null data:

```
@{
    Datetime? fromDate = ViewBag.fromDate != null ? (DateTime?)ViewBag.fromDate : null;
    Datetime? toDate = ViewBag.toDate != null ? (DateTime?)ViewBag.toDate : null;
}
```

And in your controller, please assign values to the ViewBag elements:

```
ViewBag.fromDate = fromDate;
ViewBag.toDate = toDate;
```

Comment: Or just cast with `as` to end up with the same result on each variable.

Comment: Busted by typo. Still in [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45612120/3) btw.

Comment: which code? you mean these 2 lines? ViewBag.fromDate = fromDate;
ViewBag.toDate = toDate; it is easier to copy then write them, although these are not the real fix for the issue. look up what i wrote and read the other comments. anyway, i will change these 2 lines, dont worry :)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
@{
    var fromDate = (DateTime)ViewBag.fromDate;
    var toDate = (DateTime)ViewBag.toDate;
}
```

to:

```
@{
    var fromDate = ViewBag.fromDate as DateTime?;
    var toDate = ViewBag.toDate as DateTime?;
}
```

and change:

```
<div>From Date: @Html.TextBox("fromDate", string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyy}", fromDate), new { @class = "DatePicker" })</div>
<div>To Date: @Html.TextBox("toDate", string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyy}", fromDate), new { @class = "DatePicker" })</div>
```

to:

```
<div>From Date: @Html.TextBox("fromDate", fromDate == null ? "" : string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyy}", fromDate.Value), new { @class = "DatePicker" })</div>
<div>To Date: @Html.TextBox("toDate", toDate == null ? "" : string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyy}", toDate.Value), new { @class = "DatePicker" })</div>
```

The first change will mean that the view will treat anything other than a `DateTime` as null.

The second change will ensure that `string.Format` doesn't throw an exception if it is passed a `null` (I assumed you wanted a blank string to be rendered if the date was `null`, but you can change that yourself if that doesn't meet your requirements). *Your `toDate` textbox also referenced `fromDate` (which I assumed was a typo) so I fixed that as well.*